# Android enlarge center aligned text in all directions

Tags: android, animation

I have an xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textAlignment="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myidtv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView                    
                android:text="mytext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to create animation that expands text in TextView from like 50 to 100%, but the text should remain in the center from start to the end.

I've tried with the following code but animation doesn't start with text centered.

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, (float)1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)1);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the constructor. Here is the solution. Thanks anyway.

```
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.51);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the gravity of your TextView to center will center the content within the TextView. You might try setting the gravity of the outer LinearLayout to center instead.